OAuth login with subdomain and session-based verification
I have site www.example.com that uses OAuth login system (Google, FB etc.). When use click on link, OAuth system is redirected to login.example.com, verified and redirect back to www.example.com.
I am using request verification based on value passed in state key. So when user go to OAuth I set state to some random value and when OAuth redirects back to my site, I check this state variable if it is a valid request.
However, to verify request I wanted to use SESSION storage to save state on my side. The problem is, when I do this, the SESSION variable on subdomain is empty.
My SESSION is set like this:
session_name('ID');
ini_set('session.use_cookies', 1);
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', ".example.com");
ini_set('session.cookie_samesite', 'Lax');

(I have also tried ini_set('session.cookie_domain', "example.com"))
I have tried to set None instead of Lax, but the result was still empty (plus I don't like to use None for this). How to solve this?
Instead of SESSION, is there any other way how to do the verification? I don't want to use any external libraries (Redis, memcache etc). If I use DB, I have to identify the user and IP is not enough.

I don't understand why do you need to pass session to subdomain? OAuth with state verification should look like this:

Consumer (www.example.com) generates random state and stores it in own session.
Consumer passes state to Auth Provider (login.example.com) as part of client redirect.
Auth Provider passes state back to Consumer as part of redirecting authenticated client back.
Consumer compares returned state with state stored in its own session.
Or do you mean the session is empty on Consumer  when the user comes back from Auth Provider?


I want to have login valid for multiple subdomains. So the actual "login" process is done on login.example.com (it will create sessions, write some info to DB etc). The problem is probably that the cookie with session id is not passed over OAUth system and therefore not found.

Are both www.example.com and login.example.com using the same session to begin with? (Same session name, same session storage on the server side.)

They are inited with the same shared code

So basically, what you are looking for is "Single Sign-On" solution. IMHO session shared between multiple apps is not a good idea. Because for example it would be impossible to run apps on different servers, even wrapping apps in containers might be problem. But this might be topic for discussion rather than regular question.
